# Changing the keyboard layout in Snappy Ubuntu

Tags: 15.04, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu on a usb-stick for an x86 using these instructions from https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img.xz
unxz -c ubuntu-15.04-snappy-amd64-generic.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=32M
sync
```

I'm trying to change the keyboard layout in the virtual console. I tried running `localectl list-keymaps`, but it returned

```
Couldn't find any console keymaps.
```